# Not able to Install node.js on window

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using window 7 Professinal 32 bit. 
I am able to install xampp and node.js sucessfully.

I have some code of node.js. i jst copy into htdocs/projectname

now when i run this commonad  on this path

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\nodejs>node app.js
This version of C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\nodejs\node.exe is not 
compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system informatio
n to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program,
 and then contact the software publisher.
```

Can anybody help me to configue this

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you've installed a 64-bit version of Node and need a 32-bit version.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious.